# is it possiblle to add dynamic field name in the Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add the dynamic field name and update the value according to that.in my case eventType is of 4 types delivery, send, open, click.and when i am trying to use this code i got the only eventType as a string.

```
 const event = JSON.parse(req.body);
  // const xyz = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(req.body.Message))
  // console.log(xyz)
    const message = JSON.parse(event.Message);
    console.log(message)
    const eventType = message.eventType;


  await db.collection('Emails').doc(message.mail.commonHeaders.to[0]).set(
   { eventType: message,
    timestamp: Date.now(),
  },
  { merge:false },);
```

this is an endpoint code and eventType is the event i mentioned above.

Comment: Like any JS object: `[eventType]: message`

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is here.  Please edit the question to explain what this code is doing, and how that's different than what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic keys can be added to the JSON object.

Example :

```
var key = 'age'
var keys = ['name','gender'];
var data = {};
```

Now here is a catch if you want to decide the key on runtime you need to use [], because it allows the expression to evaluate i.e.

```
data[keys[0]] = 'Rohan'
//keys[0] will interpreted to name during the execution
//data ==>> {name:'Rohan'}
```

whereas

```
data.key = '19'
//"key" will be treated as an individual entity i.e. as a valid key name
//data ==>> {key:'19'}
//whereas
data[key] = '19'
//results in data ==>> {age:'19'}
```

And also note that if you wrap a double "" inside [] it will also be treated as an individual entity

```
data['key'] = '19'
// data ==>> {key:'19'}
```

Comment: I think that the fastest way is  ```data['key'] = '19'``